# How to position a element to exact point on the background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Background img shown as fig 1, requirement

1. Width cover mobile phone screen and height adaptive
2. Position number to exact point (like fig 2)

If changing fig 1 to fig 3, i can position the single line text to exact point. 
[Please take a look in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vidolowomo/1/edit?html,css,js,output). But it did not truly solve the problem.

I have no idea how to do if background img just like fig 1. Any other ideas to to this? Thanks.

[image]

Fig 1

[image]

Fig 2

[image]

Fig 3

---

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. I got your problem right then here are some solutions put your main image inside a relative div and also put your button inside that div as an absolute position and then adjust the left , right, top, bottom property to adjust the button where you want. Make sure to use % instead of px. Let me know if you want any other help.

Comment: @Jonasw I tried something like [this](http://jsbin.com/vuqoxuvago/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Convert to svg, insert `<span>` for text, create page with responsive svg (a lot of information like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940741/making-svg-responsive) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715458/how-to-provide-responsive-design-for-svg))

Comment: What you exactly want ? what i'm thinking you want to frontend text to background image

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not entirely sure what you want.

Comment: Please forgive me for my unclear expression. In short, shown as fig 1,  i want to position "0" into "已邀请 人" and position "3" into "还差 人".Do I make myself clear？

Comment: Do you want fixed background or what? Can you explain with images or by another way?

Comment: I see only that, in fig 3 there is not 3 line ;D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please forgive me for my unclear expression and thanks for your attention.

---

Finally, i find a solution by myself.

1. convert background image (shown as fig 1) to svg
2. use [svg.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.js) to position the things i want to exact point.

[Please take a look in jsbin to see what exactly i want to position](http://jsbin.com/pujazorixa/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

I read your post and figured out that you wand something like that

Fig.1 in your background with numbers at their exact location on forground,
   like 20 in second line of yellow block of fig.2 and, 0 and 3
   in second line of red block of fig.2

well in your code which you gave at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xicakicaru/edit?html,css,js,output) you are using fig.3 and positioning text on it with code

```
<div class="chance-msg">还有20次机会，分享即可领取红包</div>
<div class="invite-msg">已邀请0人，还差3人，加油</div>
```

You can do the same thing by using fig.1 and writing only text only numbers in div you only need to position your div by adding margin left or you can use span to write your numbers in or you can just do that for a quick review

`<div class="chance-msg"><span style="visibility:hidden">还有</span>20<span style="visibility:hidden">次机会，分享即可领取红包<span></div>
  <div class="invite-msg"><span style="visibility:hidden">已邀请</span>0<span style="visibility:hidden">人，还差</span>3<span style="visibility:hidden">人，加油</span></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Fig.1 in your background with numbers at their exact location on forground, like 20 in second line of yellow block of fig.2 and, 0 and 3 in second line of red block of fig.2

well in your code which you gave at jsbin you are using fig.3 and positioning text on it with code

还有20次机会，分享即可领取红包

已邀请0人，还差3人，加油

You can do the same thing by using fig.1 and writing only text only numbers in div you only need to position your div by adding margin left or you can use span to write your numbers in or you can just do that for a quick review

还有20次机会，分享即可领取红包

已邀请0人，还差3人，加油