# Snap.svg SVG-Line Re-Render

Tags: coffeescript, snap.svg

This renders a line across the middle of the screen. This works fine.

My problem: The line **doesn't resize** when I resize the browser window.

This is the whole code (written in **CoffeeScript**, flavored with **jQuery** and **Snap.svg**):

```
$ ->
  content = Snap window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight
  content.attr
    id: 'app'
```

second part:

```
  timeline = content.line 0, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2
  timeline.attr
    id: 'timeline'
    stroke: '#000'
    strokeWidth: 2
```

The question is: How do you draw an SVG-line again and again, when the browser resizes?

Comment: Do you definitely need to, e.g would making the SVG/paper be responsive get around the problem (eg width/height 100% and set a viewbox)?

Comment: what do you mean with "**viewbox**" ?

Comment: viewBox is an svg attribute that dictates the viewable area, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715458/how-to-provide-responsive-design-for-svg for example.

Comment: no, it doesn't work this way :(

Comment: Anyway you can get an example up on a jsfiddle ?